# Parsing Data from Unknown Class

Tags: c++

I'm doing some testing on an idea that I have. However, I am at loss.
I have declared a class as such :

```
class Course {
  private:
    char *name;
    int ID;
  public:
    void printCourses();
}
```

Where `printCourses()` is defined as

```
void Course::printCourses() {
    cout << name;
}
```

This makes sense. Each class has a data member called `name`. So, say that I have declared an array of 10 class objects, that means 10 potential names will correspond with to a course...OK.

My problem lies here.

What if object 6 and 9 have those values filled at some point during runtime, and I want to KNOW that. For instance, say course 6's name is "Psychology" and course 9's name is "History". I want to be able to print these values in a sort of "Course List" function... Some class objects are not yet filled here but I want to be able to parse through and find the objects that do have the name variable filled.

I have tried a for loop for testing this but no logic is helping... I tried this.

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    course[i]->printCourses();
}
```

In my head, this should still iterate through all 10 objects (I have already allocated memory for all 10 of them), but it doesnt. However, if I just call the one I know is filled like this:

```
course[6]->printCourses();
```

It returns properly "Psychology".

TLDR: Help, How can I iterate through class objects to find certain variables that are filled ?

**disclaimer**
I am using -> operators for classes because I declared the array as an array of pointers to the class objects.

```
Course *course[10];
```

Like so..

Comment: If the member is optional you could take a look at `std::optional`

Comment: First of all I suggest to use `std::string` instead of `char*`, secondly, did you flush `cout` e.g. using std::endl? Probably the buffer is just not yet printed...

Comment: words are important: must distinct class and object (instance of class)

Comment: Don't use char *. Use string.

Comment: btw your title seems to be a bit off. There is no "unknown class" in your code

Comment: If an object of type Course is allowed to set the name after it is created (name is not provided as parameter in constructor), then your Object should also provide a method that gives the caller a hint if the name is valid or not (or set up).

Comment: You say that you implemented it as an array of pointers. So, just initialize them into zeros (nulls), and in the loop, just check for null `for (int i=0; i<10; i++) { if(courses[i] != NULL) { course[i]->printCourses(); } }`.

Comment: Agree with others: Try to move away from pointers; they aren't adding anything but problems to your code. Use `std::string` and `std::vector<Course>` instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could make a additional method that returns your name. If the name is a `nullptr`, you ignore it. Your method could look like:

```
char* Course::GetName()
{
    return name;
}
```

And then you iterate with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (course[i]->GetName())
        course[i]->printCourses();
}
```

An alternative way is to combine the functions:

```
void Course::printCourses() {
    if (name)
        std::cout << name;
}
```

Iterate with the following and it will only print the name if it exist:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    course[i]->printCourses();
}
```

It would be good to initialize the name in the constructor:

```
Course::Course() : name(nullptr), ID (0) {}
```

Little side note: Use `std::string` instead of `char*`. I provided you a solution for your case but you can do pretty much the same with a solid c++ string.

Comment: Ouch!  1.  `GetName` should return `std::string`.  2. The constructor should use the initializer list (`Course::Course() : name(nullptr), ID (0) {}`

Comment: a getter that merely returns the member and the client needs to check for nullptr? Thats encapsulation gone wrong at its best :P

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I used your constructor and check the name in the `printCourses` method. I stayed with the `char*`, because the OP wanted a solution with a `char*`.

Answer (score 0):

Before I answer, a side note. You say: "I have already allocated memory for all 10 of them." This is bad. You've wasted space on `name`s that will never be used. Instead let's use a `string` to allocate as necessary, and to allocate any number of characters as desired.

Now, you need to use [`optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) to solve this. Specifically your `name` shouldn't be definied as `char* name` but a `optional<string> name`. To use `optional` you'll just need to change your `printCourses` method:

```
void Course::printCourses() const { cout << name.value_or(""); }
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50c205f706f0c6d8)